# Get value of an interpolated string

Tags: css, less

I have the following Less code:

```
@ts-font-family-h1: @raleway;

@font-family: ~"ts-font-family-@{ts}";
font-family: @@font-family;
```

As you can see from the bottom two lines, I create a variable name (inside a mixin) and then assign the value of the variable.

I have been trying to find how to turn these two lines into one line. I'd be very surprised if it's not possible but I can't seem to find valid syntax.

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What are the values of `@raleway` and `@ts` variables?

This less code

```
a {
  @ts-font-family-h1: Arial;
  @ts: h1;    
  @font-family: ~"ts-font-family-@{ts}";

  font-family: @@font-family;
}
```

compiles to

```
a {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

without any problems.